# Does Legacy Indexing also provide the facility of Schema Indexing in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

We index in our Domain for fulltext Search

```
@Indexed(indexName = "peopleSearch", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT) 

String username
```

And schema index for password

```
@Indexed
  String password
```

In our database we have around 155 nodes of userDomain

now when we run cypher in neo4j-shell

```
 PROFILE MATCH (n:`UserDomain`) where n.username = "lTunh" RETURN n ;
```

then DB hits is 310

But if we run command

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:`UserDomain`) where n.password = "4lh7b" RETURN n
```

then DB hits is 2

Note :  `PROFILE start item=node:peopleSearch("username : *r" ) RETURN item LIMIT 25;` Db hits 8 , i.e. **Lucene Query working perfectly on username only 7 DB hits.**

We use **Spring Data Neo4j** and run Query using **Domain Repository**

So **Question** is how to achieve schema as well as fulltext indexing on username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to have both. As one of the indexes will already return a tiny amount of nodes you would just check the other property on the nodes.

And I'd go with the index on user-name and not password to be honest.

Comment: Yeah , we used password just for an example. 
In our case we use fulltext index for username in search box .

Comment: We have two fields Role and Skill in our domain . I have done full text indexing on Role as we need this field in free-text search in our application as per requirement . And I have done Schema indexing on Skill . Now I have a criteria search which is based both fields separated by OR condition in our criteria search . how could we achieve this by using benefits of both lucene and schema indexing . Does neo4j supports both type of indexing on same field or not ? Or does cypher query supports both type of index used while query execution if it involves OR condition ?